# Terraform managed_rule_group_statement and byte_match_statement in one WAF role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-waf

I want to add an exception so that selected endpoints whose url starts with /api/events, /documents/messages are not blocked by WAF. More specifically, by the rule - AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet - SQLi_BODY. The rest of the endpoints can be blocked if something is detected.

main.tf

```
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "aws_managed" {
  name        = "managed-acl"
  description = format("WAFv2 Managed ACL)
  scope       = "REGIONAL"

  default_action {
    allow {}
  }

dynamic "rule" {
  for_each = toset(var.allowed_endpoints)

  content {
    name     = rule.value.name
    priority = rule.value.priority

    statement {
      managed_rule_group_statement {
        name        = "AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
        vendor_name = "AWS"

        excluded_rule {
          name = "SQLi_BODY"
        }
      }

      byte_match_statement {
        positional_constraint = "STARTS_WITH"
        search_string         = rule.value.path
        field_to_match {
          uri_path {}
        }
        text_transformation {
          priority = 0
          type     = "NONE"
        }
      }
    }

    action {
      allow {}
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = rule.value.name
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }
}

  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
    sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    metric_name                = "waf-managed-acl"
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "allowed_endpoints" {
  type = list(object({
    name     = string
    path     = string
    priority = number
  }))
  default = []
}


and example definitions

allowed_endpoints = [
    {"name" = "access1", "path" = "/api/events", "priority" = 5},
    {"name" = "access2", "path" = "/api/informations", "priority" = 6},
    {"name" = "accces3", "path" = "/documents/messages", "priority" = 7},
]
```

The code looks correct to me, but I get an error:

```
╷
│ Error: Error updating WAFv2 WebACL: WAFInvalidParameterException: Error reason: EXACTLY_ONE_CONDITION_REQUIRED, field: STATEMENT, parameter: Statement
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "d7a51d7d-9291-43cd-91f4-820202c76236"
│   },
│   Field: "STATEMENT",
│   Message_: "Error reason: EXACTLY_ONE_CONDITION_REQUIRED, field: STATEMENT, parameter: Statement",
│   Parameter: "Statement",
│   Reason: "You have used none or multiple values for a field that requires exactly one value."
│ }
│ 
│   with aws_wafv2_web_acl.aws_managed,
│   on waf.tf line 1, in resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "aws_managed":
│    1: resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "aws_managed" {
```

However, is it not possible to add an exception for a specific role in WAF? Is my logic wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To have an action apply when multiple statements match a request, you have to wrap the statements in an [and_statement](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/4.67.0/docs/resources/wafv2_web_acl#and_statement) block. For example:

```
dynamic "rule" {
  for_each = toset(var.allowed_endpoints)

  content {
    name     = rule.value.name
    priority = rule.value.priority
    
    and_statement {
      statement {
        managed_rule_group_statement {
          name        = "AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
          vendor_name = "AWS"

          excluded_rule {
            name = "SQLi_BODY"
          }
        }
      }

      statement {
        byte_match_statement {
          positional_constraint = "STARTS_WITH"
          search_string         = rule.value.path
          field_to_match {
            uri_path {}
          }
          text_transformation {
            priority = 0
            type     = "NONE"
          }
        }
      }
    }

    action {
      allow {}
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = rule.value.name
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }
}
```

This tells the WAF to apply the `allow` action with both the `managed_rule_group_statement` **AND** the `byte_match_statement` match the incoming request.

Note that there is also an [or_statement](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/4.67.0/docs/resources/wafv2_web_acl#or_statement) block you can use when you want an action to apply if any one of a list of statements match.

---

Note that you are using the `excluded_rule` attribute in your WAF configuration, which was deprecated in the Terraform AWS provider version 4, and completely removed in version 5. You will need to upgrade at some point to the `rule_action_override` attribute, which would look like this:

```
        managed_rule_group_statement {
          name        = "AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
          vendor_name = "AWS"

          rule_action_override {
            action_to_use {
              count {}
            }

            name = "SQLi_BODY"
          }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe post a link to a GitHub gist or something with your entire Terraform file? I'm not sure how I can help debug that error without seeing the exact code causing it.